# Java find the source of memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have some problems with a memory leak in Java. I'm running a minecraft server and one of the server plugin create a huge memory leak sometimes. Here is one image with memory leak:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/znsU1.jpg

Something is creating an infinite `HashMap`, or something like that. What tools can I use to see what's inside the `HashMap`, or to see what class is creating the `HashMap`? I have to no idea where should I start to find the leak location.

This memory leak is a random thing.  It can happen after a few days, or even 2-3 times per day.

Edit 1:
Here are some images of the `HashMap` items:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOHeM.jpg

Looks like `PreciousStones` is causing this problem. Can someone confirm this ?

Edit 2:
Also I thing mineverse.Aust1n46.chat is creating a leak of string and char.  20 "async thread chat" use string and char methods every time.

Comment: Can you go through its references (using that same tool JProfiler)? And also seeing what references that/those Hashmap/s?

If that Hashmap is a kind of cache, verify that it has a clean-up mechanism (or keys expiration). Also, check if "repeated" keys are put because of a bad equals-hashCode implementations (not sure how that could be.. having 'same' objects and requiring new entries..).

Comment: Done. I think AsyncChat and PreciosStones are the source of memory leak. AsyncChat create a huge amount of String and char objects, and PreciosStone create a huge HashMap